# How can I have "names" for my background processes (not just the command)?

Tags: background-process, jobs

I run a lot of vim windows, and often put them in the bg. The problem is that they all say `vim` when I list `jobs` so it's hard to distinguish.

```
[1]  - suspended  nvim
[2]  - suspended  nvim
[3]  + suspended  nvim
```

One way around this is to open a specific file when starting vim:

```
nvim ./myfile
```

`jobs`:

```
[1]  + suspended  nvim myfile
```

But this is a poor substitute for a name.

Another option is to (mis)use env vars like this to name the buffer:

```
vim name=my_name
```

But the output of `jobs` could be more usable, and has the disadvantage of needing to preparing for the possibly unneeded backgrounding of the process at the moment of staring the process.

```
[1]  - suspended  nvim name=my_name
[2]  + suspended  nvim name=other_name
```

Ideally I'd like to be asked to give the process an optional name when I press `ctl-z`. Perhaps there's a plugin out there that handles this, but I haven't found it.

I would consider writing it myself, but I wouldn't know where to start. Presumably by re-mapping `ctl-z` to some other program? And maybe I'd have to write something that sites in front of `fg` and `jobs` as well to control the output...

Any suggestions for this?

Comment: It might be simpler to use just one nvim command, and have it open multiple files, each in a buffer. There are commands in vim to navigate between buffers.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a shell function `nvim` which checks for background jobs which match its name and current arguments. If one is found then it is brought back in the foreground. If not, a new command line is run.

Instead of typing the whole command again you can use the shell history:

1. You started the new command `nvim foo.txt`
2. You put this command in the background.
3. [with a typical bash configuration] Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> should show you `nvim foo.txt` so you just have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the command line again which calls the shell function and gets you back to your suspended vim process.

## Response to comment

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> does not work like that. It is not assigned any configurable shell function. You can check in `bash` for all letters (and several other characters):

```
start cmd:> bind -p | grep -F '\C-a'
"\C-a": beginning-of-line
```

Most of them have some configuration in the shell (i.e. in `readline`, its prompt editing component) but not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>. The reason is that this is defined elsewhere, with "higher priority" so that it would never reach the shell anyway:

```
start cmd:> stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 47; columns 210; line = 0;
intr = ^C; [...] kill = ^U; eof = ^D; [...] start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z;
```

The terminal emulator catches this key combination and sends a `SIGTSTP` (TERMINAL STOP) signal to the foreground process group:

```
start cmd:> strace -f -p 20171
strace: Process 20171 attached
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted read ...>) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
--- SIGTSTP {si_signo=SIGTSTP, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
--- stopped by SIGTSTP ---
--- SIGCONT {si_signo=SIGCONT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=3583, si_uid=1000} ---
```

That's what is happening on the kernel level. The foreground process is stopped (because it does not trap this signal) and the shell is informed that its child process has received a signal from the kernel and has been stopped. Running `fg` causes the last line, the continuation signal being sent from the user process (the shell).

Comment: Interesting idea. But 1) I want this to work with any process (not just nvim) and 2) I don't usually start nvim with any arguments.

Comment: Would ideally like to figure out how to make `ctrl-z` go do a different command that handles the naming and then the listing of jobs.

Comment: @pixelearth See my answer edit.

Comment: I found that in iTerm I can map `ctl-z` to any program I want. I tried to write something that would run something before the backgroudning, but I couldn't figure out anything that worked. I also could figure out how to execute what the original `ctl-z` would do from the bash file.

Comment: @pixelearth Sure, the terminal emulator can do whatever it wants to do. But that does not affect the shell's view of job control.